# Generating list that matches criteria from larger list

Tags: arrays, excel, list, excel-formula

Trying to write a function in Excel that will pull data from the larger list on the left and display a smaller list that matches criteria given. For example, I want to itemize each salespersons vehicles individually as a list under their names on the right. Is there an easy way to do this? I was thinking about generating an array based off of the sales reps name in E:E, then using =offset() to pull the vehicle model and display it under the reps name. But I can't think of a way to do this. Any pointers would be great.

[image: Example]

Comment: Does your version of Excel support FILTER?

Comment: If you have FILTER() that is available in Office 365: `=FILTER(B:D,E:E=MID($I$5,find(" ",$I$5)+1,999) & ", " & LEFT($I$5,find(" ",$I$5)-1))`